# ASP.NET / MVC 4 bundling and minification 404 issues on 64-bit IIS 7.5 server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-4.5, bundling-and-minification

We recently upgraded our project from MVC 3  to MVC 4. We are targeting the .NET 4.0 framework, and our web app is 32-bit due to some references we have to include.

The problem we are having is that we converted our bundling / minification from Chirpy to the built-in ASP.NET bundling. The site runs with no problems on 32-bit servers, both Windows Server 2003/IIS 6 and 2008/IIS 7.5 running ONLY .NET 4.0, and our 64-bit development machines.  The bundling / minification works fine on all of the above.

On a 64-bit Windows 2008 / IIS 7.5 server with ONLY .NET 4.0 installed, bundling does not work. We get 404 errors for both the generated scripts and styles.

If we install .NET 4.5 on the 64-bit server, it works fine. We are confused by this because some servers work without .NET 4.5, and this one requires it. On top of that, Windows Server 2003 / 64-bit is not compatible with .NET 4.5 so if that has an issue as well, this fix won't work.

The weird thing is, the sample MVC 4 sample internet app targeting .NET 4.0 built x86 works fine with just 4.0 on the problem server. The web.config is exactly the same except for unity, logging, elmah, and dot less configuration.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Here's the BundleConfig.cs:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace WebApp
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.UseCdn = false;

            // .debug.js, -vsdoc.js and .intellisense.js files 
            // are in BundleTable.Bundles.IgnoreList by default.
            // Clear out the list and add back the ones we want to ignore.
            // Don't add back .debug.js.
            bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
            bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("*-vsdoc.js");
            bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("*intellisense.js");

            bundles.Add((new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/WebApp.Register1")).Include("~/Scripts/jquery.ba-tinypubsub.min.js",       
                                                                                 "~/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js",
                                                                                 "~/Scripts/WebApp/WebApp.Register.RegisterStudent.js",
                                                                                 "~/Scripts/WebApp/WebApp.Register.RegisterPresenter.js"));

            bundles.Add((new Bundle("~/bundles/WebApp.Register2")).Include("~/Scripts/WebApp/WebApp.Register.StudentSelect.js"));


            bundles.Add((new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/WebApp.View1")).Include("~/Scripts/jquery.ba-tinypubsub.min.js",
                                                                             "~/Scripts/WebApp/WebApp.View.ImagePresenter.js", 
                                                                             "~/Scripts/WebApp/WebApp.View.ImageResults.js"));

            bundles.Add((new Bundle("~/bundles/WebApp.View2")).Include("~/Scripts/WebApp/WebApp.View.StudentsSelect.js"));

            bundles.Add((new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/WebApp.Print1")).Include("~/Scripts/WebApp/WebApp.Print.SelectedIdArray.js",
                                                                              "~/Scripts/jquery.ba-tinypubsub.min.js",
                                                                              "~/Scripts/WebApp/WebApp.Print.DocumentsSelect.js",
                                                                              "~/Scripts/WebApp/WebApp.Print.DocumentsSelected.js",
                                                                              "~/Scripts/WebApp/WebApp.Print.DocumentsPresenter.js",
                                                                              "~/Scripts/WebApp/WebApp.Print.StudentsPresenter.js",
                                                                              "~/Scripts/WebApp/WebApp.Print.PrinterSelected.js",
                                                                              "~/Scripts/WebApp/WebApp.Print.OutputSummary.js",
                                                                              "~/Scripts/WebApp/WebApp.Print.OutputPresenter.js",
                                                                              "~/Scripts/WebApp/WebApp.Print.NoStudentPresenter.js"));

            bundles.Add((new Bundle("~/bundles/WebApp.Print2")).Include("~/Scripts/WebApp/WebApp.Print.StudentsSelect.js",
                                                                        "~/Scripts/WebApp/WebApp.Print.StudentsSelected.js"));

            bundles.Add((new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/WebApp.Main")).Include("~/Scripts/modernizr.custom.33607.js", 
                                                                            "~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.js",
                                                                            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js",
                                                                            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js", 
                                                                            "~/Scripts/json.js",
                                                                            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js", 
                                                                            "~/Scripts/jquery.marquee.js",
                                                                            "~/Scripts/YUI.js", 
                                                                            "~/Scripts/Common.SearchHighlight.js"));

            bundles.Add((new StyleBundle("~/bundles/Content/WebApp.Main")).Include("~/Content/jquery.marquee.min.css",
                                                                                      "~/Content/YUI.css", 
                                                                                      "~/Content/Site.css",
                                                                                      "~/Content/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how we're referencing the bundles in our layout:

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/WebApp.Main")
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/SiteLess.less")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/Content/WebApp.Main")
    ...
```

EDIT: Responses / updates

- Yes, the Enabled 32-bit apps flag is set to True in the app pool.
- The path to the request that gives the 404 looks like this http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/WebApp/bundles/WebApp.Main?v=03pBc7hdH1lHLtZGx-JMosNaLpMK7fcmI0uI6auknHw1
- Windows event viewer shows nothing
- It works after installing .NET 4.5, uninstalling it, then reinstalling .NET 4.0
- It works on an enterprise 2008 64-bit Server. The problem server is standard edition. We are going to rebuild the VM to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: This might help http://forums.asp.net/t/1846749.aspx/2/10?Published+MVC+web+to+IIS7+in+Windows+Server+2008+doesn+t+serve+bundles

Comment: Post your BudleConfig.cs please

Comment: @Jack Thanks, we did read through that thread and make the changes suggested, but it didn't help. Ours actually works fine out of the box with just .NET 4.0 AND .NET 4.5 installed on the 64-bit box. I did not think .NET 4.5 was a requirement.

Comment: @CrazyCoderz OK- just added it.

Comment: Have you compared content of both websites (after publish)? I believe there will be a .net 4.5 dll in the working websites that is missing on erroneous one

Comment: Bundle Config looks ok. Stupid question but in your app pool for your IIS site do you have Enable 32-Bit Applications Set to True??

Comment: Clear your event logs and reproduce the issue, something should be logged

Comment: Also can you send me the path for the 404 google chrome console should show this when you inspect the page.

Comment: @CrazyCoderz Updated post with responses.

Comment: It works on a 64-bit 2008 server (enterprise edition) with just .NET 4.0. The one that was failing was standard edition. We are going to rebuild the VM from scratch to see if that helps.

Comment: Try to add into the <modules> section <remove name="BundleModule" /> <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" /> this will probably fix your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be with the .NET 4.0 installation on the VM we were using for that server. After creating two new VMs (both Windows 2008 64-bit, one standard one enterprise) with clean .NET 4.0 installs, the bundling worked fine on both. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Can you please share details of what "clean .NET 4.0" means

Comment: Clean meaning a completely new install of .NET 4.0. I saw your comment below, that's interesting. I'm not able to test this as I'm at a new job now.

Comment: Just for any others with this problem, I solved my version of the problem by adding an entry to the web.config <system.webserver> <modules> section to add the BundleModule:  
<remove name="BundleModule" /> 
<add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />

Answer (score 2):

The environment where you initially experienced 404 issues likely did not have the extensionless URLs hotfix applied.

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368

Coincidentally, your "clean .NET 4.0" install either was a version later than 4.0 (perhaps 4.5?) or you may have unknowingly applied the hotfix / update to enable support for extensionless URLs.

I ran into same problem in Windows Server 2008 boxes (Enterprise; both 32bit and 64bit), where the bundler was not failing at runtime (it was correctly creating bundles, and correctly rendering the bundle URL, like `/app/bundles/my_script`), but IIS was returning 404 for the bundle URL. I installed hotfix 980368 and the bundles starting working.